# aws cli describe-parameters ( SSM )

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm, aws-parameter-store

I am trying to loop through and echo all my parameters to a file.

I am using describe-parameters and it is giving an error of

> An error occurred (ThrottlingException) when calling the
> DescribeParameters operation (reached max retries: 2): Rate exceeded

I have ( in bash )

```
#bash!
for params in $(aws ssm describe-parameters)
do
    echo -n $params
done > Output/DiffTryssmParameters_$dt.json
```

it gives the error above.
I have looked and looked and there are no solutions thus far other than increasing the limit within the account. ( Root access, not workable ).

I have tried various parameters like --max-item
and even tried making that a variable i and using i++ and sleep 0.1 or 1 this all did not work.

Please does anyone have any advice or a different aws cli command to output all parameters.

This way I can also automate correcting non-secure strings to secure strings.

Thanks so much for forthcoming help :)

Comment: You may also want to pass `parameter-filters` to avoid getting parameters which are already `SecureString`.

Comment: Will this sort the throttling issue though?

Comment: It will not but it will certainly save you some $$$ in long run.

Answer (score 1):

You are being throttled. Your only option is to send requests less frequently.

Options to accomplish this include:

1. introduce a pause/sleep between requests (for example [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff))
2. investigate awscli [configurable retry options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-retries.html)

Comment: there doesn't look to be a way to sleep between requests as it seems to cache the whole request:
notSecureParams=$(aws ssm describe-parameters --filters "Key=Type,Values=String")
    echo $notSecureParams ) > output/describe-ssm-parameters_$dt.json